# Using Futures with Dart

Tags: dart

Why is the print result keep returning "asd"?

```
      var jerl = "asd";

  HttpRequest.request('Foo',
    method: "GET",
    requestHeaders: {"Authorization": "Secret"}).then((x) => x.responseText).then((y) => jerl = y);

  print(jerl);
```

Comment: this doesn't look like angularjs code....

Comment: Must have added it subconsciously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Async code is just scheduled for later execution and the sync code continues executing without waiting for the async code. The method you pass to `Future.then(...)` is executed when the scheduled async code is finished. You find a lot of such questions and examples tagged [:dart-async:] here on StackOverflow.

If you want code to be executed when the async code completed you need to chain it with `then` like you did with other code

```
var jerl = "asd";

HttpRequest.request('Foo',
  method: "GET",
  /* return */ requestHeaders: {"Authorization": "Secret"})
  .then((response) {
    var jer1 = x.responseText;
    print(jerl);
  });
```

You can use the `async`/`await` feature to make code look more like sync code

```
Future someMethod() async { // <== added `Future` and `async`
  var jerl = "asd";

  var response = await HttpRequest.request('Foo',  // <== added `await`
    method: "GET",
    requestHeaders: {"Authorization": "Secret"}).then((x) => 
  print(response.text);
}
```

`async` is contagious. There is no way to go back from async execution to sync execution. If your code calls any async method or function and you need code further down to wait for the async result, then you need to chain all following code (also in calling methods) with `.then` (or use `async`/`await`). For this to work you also need to `return` the future to the caller so he can call `.then()` on it.

With `async`/`await` you don't need to explicitly return the future.

`async`/`await` doesn't make async code sync (as mentioned above), it only makes it **look** more like sync code. The underlying behavior is identical as with `then`.